# In RxJS, what is the difference between interval and timeInterval operator?

Tags: rxjs

I tried to google it, but I cannot find any clear answer for that.
From the documentation, I noticed that one is operator, and one is function.

What is the difference between them? and what should I use in my code?

Thanks!

Here is the documentation link:

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/timeInterval

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/interval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`interval()` is a so called Observable creation method that returns an Observable that emits periodically an ever increasing sequence of numbers with a constant delay between them.

`timeInterval()` is an operator that basically "timestamps" each emission from its source with time between the two most recent emissions.

The main and probably more obvious difference is how you use them:

```
range(1, 20).pipe(
  timeInterval(), // `timeInterval()` is an operator
).subscribe(...); // TimeInterval objects

interval(1000).pipe( // `interval()` is a source Observable
).subscribe(...); // 0, 1, 2, ...
```

Comment: Many thanks! really hope the official document would be as clear as this!